# Ошибка при установки MODX на OpenServer

Tags: modx

Скачал MODX 2.8 (пробовал также 3.0). Закинул в созданий каталог в каталог доменов для OpenServer (хотя как то странно оно разархивировалось - ! E:\My_Server\OSPanel\domains\florida\modx-2.8.4.zip: Невозможно создать папку E:\My_Server\OSPanel\domains\florida\modx-2.8.4\modx-2.8.4-pl.
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
).
При открытии локального сайта, вместо того чтоб увидеть начало установки движка я вижу ошибку "Could not load MODX config file."

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Нужно было самостоятельно указать пусть к каталогу установки, т.е. /setup

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).